# R - Update Dataframe Values in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

How can I change the values of B by inputting different values for A with an R Shiny dashboard?
The output I would like to get is a different dataframe with the updated values, that I can use for visualizations purposes.

#### Data

```
test <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(3,6,7), ncol = 1))
colnames(test) <- "A"
test <- test %>% mutate(B = 2*A,
                        C = 3*B)
```

I would like to have a R Shiny dashboard that allows me to manually change the values of A and then updates the 'test' df so that the values of B and C are a result of the new values of A.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your shiny dashboard (server section)

```
test <- reactive({ test %>%  mutate(B=2*A, C=3*B) })
```

You can access the new columns `B` and `C` in the dataframe

```
test()
```

and it gets updated every time you change `A`.